# Ti.Media.Android.scanMediaFiles for Absolute Path

Tags: android, file, filesystems, titanium, media

i have this code :

```
var imgPath = 'file:///sdcard/MyMobileProject/Images/Resize/';
var imgDir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(imgPath);

if (!imgDir.exists()){
    imgDir.createDirectory();
}

var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(imgPath, filename);
f.write(image);

Titanium.Media.Android.scanMediaFiles([f.nativePath], ["image/jpeg"]);
```

When i try to do a mediaScan with relative path such as :

```
var imgPath = Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory + '/Resize/';
```

It works perfectly, but after i changed the path into an absolute path, it won't works for me.. The device is creating new file on the absolute path, but my windows explorer can't find that file because scanMediaFiles function won't work in this case..

Does anyone know how to do a scanMediaFiles with an absolute path? so i can get the image that created by my app from windows explorer.. Thanks..

Comment: @Frans: Did you got solution.?

Answer (score 1):

You almost there @Frans..

You have to just convert your directory path to abs path..

**instead of this..**

```
var imgPath = Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory + '/Resize/';
```

**change to ..**

```
var imgPath = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory + '/Resize/');
```

**Remaining all same code..**

```
var imgDir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(imgPath);
if (!imgDir.exists()){
imgDir.createDirectory();
}

var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(imgPath, filename);
f.write(image);

Titanium.Media.Android.scanMediaFiles([f.nativePath], ["image/jpeg"]);
```